# Forcing page numbers to ignore large margins

Tags: margins, page-numbering, geometry

My teacher wants a large space to post comments on my work, so I have placed a bottom margin of 10 cm to pdfLatex. But the problem is that Latex also moves the page numbers up along with the margins so that the page numbers end up almost in the middle of the page. How can I force the page numbers to stick to the bottom of the actual page? My current document looks like:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdfborder={1 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[bottom=10cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
%Lots of work here
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to welcome you here... Here I am: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value of `foot` when loading `geometry`. This sets the distance between the text and the footer. For example, setting `foot=9cm` leaves 9cm between the text and the footer.

So, the following MWE could be what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[pdfborder={1 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[bottom=10cm,foot=9cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]